# Home widget - Is it inefficient for UI event handler registration be done multiple times through onUpdate

Tags: android

So far, all the `AppWidgetProvider` code example I had seen, they placed UI event handler register code in `onUpdate`.

However, isn't this is some how inefficient? As I thought UI event handler registration just need to be done 1 time.

`onUpdate` will always be triggered repeatably.

Is there any more efficient way?

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

  private static final String ACTION_CLICK = "ACTION_CLICK";

  @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
      int[] appWidgetIds) {

      ...

      // Register an onClickListener
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);

      intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
      intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
          0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
      remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.update, pendingIntent);
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me put it in this way.

Remote views are not the real views, but rather a set of rules, which is used to create real views. Then you call `updateAppWidget()`, then this set of rules gets sent to Android, and Android creates new views by applying these rules. `OnClickPendingIntent` is one of those rules. If it's there, then it gets applied and you have a listener set.

If you create a new instance of `remoteViews`, then you have to provide a `OnClickPendingIntent` to this instance too. If you don't, then there will be no listener registered and you won't get a callback. In this regards, you do not set listener twice or multiple times at the same instance - because you always re-create `remoteViews` too - and this is optimal.

Android might apply additional optimization by reusing already existing views, if remote views were not changed. But this is something out of your control.